# Using a WHERE clause subquery, select the greatest 1 per group with a tie-breaker

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group, arcgis

I have a RoadInsp table in a SQLite 3.38.2 database. I've put the data in a CTE for purpose of this question:

```
with roadinsp (objectid, asset_id, date_, condition) as (
values
(1, 1, '2016-04-01', 20),
(2, 1, '2019-03-01', 19),
(3, 1, '2022-01-01', 18),
  
(4, 2, '2016-04-01', 17),
(5, 2, '2022-01-01', 16),
  
(6, 3, '2022-03-01', 15),  --duplicate date
(7, 3, '2022-03-01', 14),  --duplicate date
(8, 3, '2019-01-01', 13)
)  
select * from roadinsp

objectid  asset_id      date_   condition
       1         1  2016-04-01         20
       2         1  2019-03-01         19
       3         1  2022-01-01         18

       4         2  2016-04-01         17
       5         2  2022-01-01         16

       6         3  2022-03-01         15
       7         3  2022-03-01         14
       8         3  2019-01-01         13
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UwabK8d9)

---

I'm using GIS software that only lets me use SQL in a WHERE clause/SQL expression, not a full SELECT query.

I want to select the *greatest 1 per group* using a WHERE clause. In other words, for each ASSET_ID, I want to select the row that has the latest date.

I can achieve that using a WHERE clause expression like this:

```
date_ = 
  (select max(subq.date_) from roadinsp subq where roadinsp.asset_id = subq.asset_id)

objectid  asset_id      date_   condition
       3         1  2022-01-01         18
       5         2  2022-01-01         16
       6         3  2022-03-01         15
       7         3  2022-03-01         14
```

That works, but it selects two rows for asset #3, since there are two rows with the same date for that asset.

So I want to break the tie by selecting the row that has the highest condition value. It would look like this:

```
objectid  asset_id  date_       condition
       3         1  2022-01-01         18
       5         2  2022-01-01         16
       6         3  2022-03-01         15  --this row has a higher condition value than the other duplicate row.
                                           --so the other duplicate row was omitted.
```

I only ever want to select one row per asset. So if there are duplicate condition values too, then it doesn't matter what condition is selected, as long as only one row is selected.

---

Using a WHERE clause subquery, how can I select the *greatest 1 per group*, and break ties using the row that has the greatest condition?

Comment: You should clarify what you want: *it doesn't matter which one is selected* or the *row that has a higher condition value*. Also, is there a case that 2 rows for the same asset_id and the same date may have the same condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use IN() with ORDER BY and LIMIT to check the primary key...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM roadinsp r
 WHERE objectid IN (
         SELECT objectid
           FROM roadinsp
          WHERE asset_id = r.asset_id
       ORDER BY date_ DESC, condition DESC
          LIMIT 1
       )
```

This is easily extended to `n` rows per asset. And additional conditions can easily be added to the ORDER BY.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8BVrb3q)

Comment: What is the point of IN? The subquery returns 1 row with 1 column.

Comment: @forpas Because the op title asked for greatest n, the body kept repeating greatest n, and so I generalised for n

Comment: @MatBailie Good one. This is very sargable.

Comment: Tested this query with 10K rows and a (asset_id, date_ desc, condition desc) index created. The response is instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could add another similar condition to the *where* clause (as I understand your question, that's all you can modify?):

```
select * 
from roadinsp r
where 
  date_ = (
    select max(subq.date_) 
    from roadinsp subq 
    where r.asset_id = subq.asset_id
 )
 and condition = (
   select Max(condition) 
   from roadinsp c 
   where c.date_ = r.date_ 
   and c.asset_id = r.asset_id
);
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qu6Xlg09)

Answer (score -1):

**REQUIREMENTS**

- I'm using GIS software that only lets me use SQL in a WHERE clause/SQL expression, not a full SELECT query.
- Using a WHERE clause subquery, how can I select the greatest n per group, and break ties with the row that has the largest condition?

**BUSINESS RULES**

- For each `asset_id`, pick the one with most recent `date_`
- If there are more than one row on the same `date_`, pick the one with largest `condition`

**SOLUTION**

- Concatenate `date_` and `condition` into one and then pick the max() as below:
- Add leading 0s depends on max number of digits of `condition`

```sql
select * 
  from roadinsp
 where date_ || substr('00'||condition,-2,2) = 
  (select max(subq.date_ || substr('00'||condition,-2,2)) from roadinsp subq where roadinsp.asset_id = subq.asset_id);
```

Outcome:

```
objectid|asset_id|date_     |condition|
--------+--------+----------+---------+
       3|       1|2022-01-01|       18|
       5|       2|2022-01-01|       16|
       6|       3|2022-03-01|       15|
```

UPDATE:

- If there're more than one row with the same `date_` and `condition`, add `objectid` to the list:

```
select * 
  from roadinsp
 where (date_ || substr('00'||condition,-2,2) || substr('00000000'||objectid,-8,8)) = 
  (select max(subq.date_ || substr('00'||condition,-2,2) || substr('00000000'||objectid,-8,8)) from roadinsp subq where roadinsp.asset_id = subq.asset_id);
```

Comment: This does not work: https://dbfiddle.uk/p552h7sV

Comment: @forps fixed code to add leading 0s. thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Non-sargable lookup.